# AbstractMethodError javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty

I know that this error kinda implicates dependency/runtime issues yet I can't seem to find the offending dependencies. As from my stackoverflow/google research this happens if you mix jersey versions or using jax-rs 2.0 with jersey 1.0 but all my jersey dependencies are 2.22.1 and I can see in the referenced libraries that jax-rs is used in version 2.0.1.

The maven dependencies I'm using are:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
      <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Java code used (if the code matters) (basically taken from an online tutorial):

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
            ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    Server jettyServer = new Server(9090);
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
            "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
            EntryPoint.class.getCanonicalName());

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
```

Trace of `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ hadoopy ---
[INFO] ch.foob.mumi:hadoopy:jar:0.0
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-daemon:commons-daemon:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.1.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8:system
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.7.v20160115:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.7.v20160115:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.7.v20160115:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.7.v20160115:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.7.v20160115:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.7.v20160115:compile
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jetty-http:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.1.1.v20140108:compile
```

Comment: Try running `mvn dependency:tree` if you haven't already. It can help track this sort of thing down

Comment: I've added the output to the question (at the bottom).

Comment: It looks like hadoop is using some version of jetty/jersey itself. Is that problem?

Comment: Hadoop is definitely the problem

Comment: And how can I fix that?

Comment: Use a 1.x version of Jersey.